# Can I use a form's is_valid function for DRF submitted data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a form (not a ModelForm) with custom validators that's working fine. Now need to add an API for submitting the same data. Is it possible to use the form's is_valid() function to validate the data?

I tried populating a new form instance using initial, but the form is never valid. Tried in the shell with a simple form and saw the same thing.

```
# ./manage.py shell
Python 3.6.10 (default, Jan 17 2021, 19:51:05) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django import forms
>>> class DogForm(forms.Form):
...   name = forms.CharField(max_length=6)
...   age = forms.IntegerField()
... 
>>> df = DogForm(initial={'name':'Rex','age':3})
>>> df.is_valid()
False
```

I'm missing a step somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use your form to validate serializer post data, all you have to do is provide a custom `validate` serializer method.

Here's a code example of how to implement it (i don't know if it works well with `forms.Form` so you'll have to try it.):

```
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    form_class = FormExample # some dummy form

    def validate(self, attrs):
        # Check if we have a form_class defined
        if hasattr(self, "form_class") and self.form_class != None:
            self.form: forms.ModelForm = self.form_class(
                instance=self.instance,
                data=attrs
            )
            # Check if data is clean
            if not self.form.is_valid():
                raise serializers.ValidationError(self.form.errors)

            return attrs

        # If you don't provide a form class, the default validate will run
        return super().validate(attrs=attrs)
```

You can use this class as a base `ModelSerializer` if you want.